# Visual Basic Table Drawing Tools

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I am trying to create an interactive table which can display work shifts for a given week. I wanted the table to look something like this.
[image]
I've managed to recreate something like this using VB.net, however I have done it in (what I consider to be) a ridiculous way. I have used a TableLayoutPanel with a column for each day and a row for each hour of the day. This works, looks okay, and also allows editing of shifts. (I.e, you click in a cell to turn it green and add it to a shift).  [image]
The problems with this solution are (a) there is no easy way to represent half hours, or quarter hour segments easily and (b) the fact that each cell contains a blank label which then gets coloured in, the form takes a long time (~ 6 seconds) to load, which seems unnecessary to me. What would be a better way to implement something similar to this? Preferably without using the VB reporting, since I can't seem to get that to work, though that's a separate issue.
Thanks.

Comment: **MAYBE** it is possible with ListView i don't know but give it a try :)

Comment: Derive your own class from Control, you a List(Of Appointment) and code in the OnPaint() method override.  Shouldn't take more than a couple of dozen milliseconds.  Re-inventing Outlook isn't the greatest idea btw.

Comment: @HansPassant Hahah it's not a reinvention of outlook, its just a project for college. Can you explain a bit more on what you mean by deriving my own class? It's not something I've done before

Comment: Derive = inherit. You create a custom control inheriting `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. In it you override the `OnPaint()` method to draw the control yourself.

Comment: @VisualVincent But I don't quite understand what I would put in the OnPaint method. Wouldn't adding the labels as I do now be just as slow there as it is at the moment. Or would I paint each cell using this OnPaint method, without having to create something in each cell?

Comment: In the `OnPaint` method you are supposed to utilize the `PaintEventArgs` parameter sent to it, which contains a `Graphics` class. Using the `Graphics` class you now have access to various methods for performing drawing. However it might be a bit complicated, I don't know how used you are to using the `Graphics` class. Here's a small article about custom drawn controls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, and to answer your question properly: No, you are not supposed to create any objects from the `OnPaint` method. Overriding the `OnPaint` method you will be able to draw directly onto the control, which is pretty fast. Unless `OnPaint` is called also _for each cell_ (you can find out if it does via the `PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle` property) you would have to calculate the cells' position and size on your own. -- You could inherit your custom control from `TableLayoutPanel` instead of just from `Control`, so it will still handle how the cells work.